# How to create a bitmap from ViewRenderable / Node using SceneForm?

Tags: arcore, sceneform, google-filament

[image: imageview source in ViewRenderable]

I'm currently displaying the above image (black is transparent actually) over the augmented image, using Sceneform (Maintained repo by Thomas Gorisse, which is based on ARCore and filament).

[image: Output and bitmap I wish to extract]

Is there any method by which I could screenshot only the ViewRenderable node displayed in Augmented Camera output ? I need the bitmap output of what is shown in the node, as exactly as shown in the output.

Comment: So you want to take a screenshot while looking at the augmented image from a certain perspective and that screenshot must only contain the node and not anything else?

Comment: yes, indeed. I want the overlayed image node as a bitmap in short.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @Regis_AG : Nope. My purpose was to get the shape of the node actually, which I later achieved by using the center anchor node + imagewidth/2 calculations, and using that 4 sides creating a bitmap, in screen coordinates ...